# cloudbees jenkins maven installation missing

Tags: maven, jenkins, cloudbees

I am getting following error when building a project in jenkins:

ERROR: A Maven installation needs to be available for this project to be built.Either your server has no Maven installations defined, or the requested Maven version does not exist.
[cloudbees-deployer] Skipping deployment as build result is FAILURE
Finished: FAILURE

In Jenkins settings, I tried both options: automatic installation from apache as well as use pre-installed maven on dev@cloud.

What might be missing?

Comment: what's you account so I can check configuration ?